# Route Data Subscription in Angular is not triggerd from resolver

Tags: angular

I've a component, that displays detail on top and a select options which gets populated after an `API` call. I've used the select option to determine the next route.

I've used router-outlet to load the component on the basis of selected option. All the components to be loaded are lazy loaded.

`Template`

```
<div>
    Detail Section
</div>

<div> Select Option Section </div>
<div>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

I've routes array as below:-

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: ':id',
    component: ParentComponent,
    canActivate: [AppRouteGuard],
    children: [
        {
            path: 'path1',
            loadChildren:'path-to-module',
            canActivate: [AppRouteGuard]
       },
       ...
    ]
  }
];
```

Say I've a variable viz `routeSelector` which determines route to be hit. All the children routes are lazy loaded modules. I need the `routeSelector` variable to determine `API` endpoint to be hit in `Resolver` in each of `Child Modules`.

So when I first navigate to the parent route i.e. `/:id` as per the above routes array, I store the variable in service so that I could subscribe to the value whenever I need.

Everything works fine, if I navigate to child routes selecting any of the options. But if I'm in child route i.e. `/:id/path1`, I could not get the value of `routeSelector` variable in resolver on the first hit. Subsequently    the `routeSelector` value is retreived resulting in API call, but result is not reflected in the component.

`Service Code`

```
@Injectable()
export class ServiceName() {
   private subject$ = new BehaviorSubject('');
   constructor() { }  

   getRouteSelector() {
       return this.subject$ as Observable;
   }

   setRouteSelector(str: string) {
    this.subject$.next(str);
  }

}
```

`Resolver Code`

```
resolve(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<model1 | model2> {
    const id= route.params.id;
    let observable$: Observable<model1| model2>;

    this._routeSelectorService.getRouteSelector()
      .subscribe((routeSelector) => {
        if (routeSelector) {
          switch (routeSelector) {
            case 'Model 1':
              observable$ = this._model1Service.getModel1(id);
              break;
            case 'Model 2':
              observable$ = this._model2Service.getModel2(id);
              break;
          }
        }
      });
    return observable$;
  }
}
```

`Component Code`

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.routeDataSubscription = this.route.data.subscribe(
      ({ model}) => {
        this.model= model;
        // Checks if model is received or not and set a value to a bool
        // say `isDataReceived`
      }
    );
  }
}
```

`Component Template Code`

```
<div *ngIf="isDataReceived; else noData">
    Display the Model Value
</div>

<ng-template #noData>
   No Data Received
</ng-template>
```

Thus on refreshing the page, I always end up getting `else` section of the template.

How can I solve this? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `observable$` will effectively always return before `subscribe()` is executed due to its asynchronous nature. If the goal is to return an observable from either `getModel1()` or `getModel2()`, you can use an RxJS pipeable operator such as [switchMap()](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html) instead of using `subscribe()`:

```
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

// ...

resolve(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<model1 | model2> {
    const id = route.params.id;

    return this._routeSelectorService.getRouteSelector()
      .pipe(switchMap(routeSelector) => {
        if (routeSelector) {
          switch (routeSelector) {
            case 'Model 1':
              return this._model1Service.getModel1(id);
            case 'Model 2':
              return this._model2Service.getModel2(id);
            default:
              return of(null); // need to handle when not 'Model 1' or 'Model 2'
          }
        } else {
          return of(null); // need to handle falsy `routeSelector` value
        }
      });
  }
}
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: It doesn't work...Now the route to `/:id/path` doesn't get routed

Comment: Can you please share the code for getRouteSelector()?

Comment: I've updated question showing the getRouteSelector() method in service